# How to make flashlight Blink in android

Tags: java, android, performance

In my code after exiting from thread the flash light is still on. I can't   understand the logical error. How can I turn the flash light off at the end of the thread?

```
Thread thread = new Thread((new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        SystemClock.sleep(200);
        int led = 1;
        while (blink_enabler) { 
           if (led == 1) {
                params = cam.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                cam.setParameters(params);
                cam.startPreview();
                led = 0;
            } else {
                params = cam.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                cam.setParameters(params);
                cam.stopPreview();
                led = 1;
            }
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        }
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        cam.stopPreview();
    }
}));
```

Comment: you lack a `cam.setParameters(params);` before calling `cam.stopPreview();` on the exit part.

Comment: thanks for the response but it does not solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the while loop, set the parameters for the camera before `stopPreview()`:

```
params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
cam.setParameters(params);
cam.stopPreview();
```